# ClassNotFoundException with URLClassLoader in classes.jar (java.net package)

Tags: eclipse, classnotfoundexception, urlclassloader

On Eclipse Galileo, got the following ClassNotFoundException when doing Debug As/Web Application. But works just fine when doing Run As/Web Application.

I was given message that "The source attachment does not contain the source for the file URLClassLoader.class. You can change the source attachment by clicking the Change Attached Source below:"

In the project window, it seems that the URLClassLoader class is from Java.net package, which is from /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Classes/classes.jar.

I found the jar on the machine, what else I am missing? why it's debug only issue?

Could it be possible that the JRE system library that I have on my iMac 10.6.5 machine is outdated? Or somehow install/unstall of some jar/package caused the issue?

This is what I have - JRE System Library [JVM 1.6.0 (MacOS X Default)] - would update it help fixing the issue? but how to get it updated?

Please help!

```
com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain at localhost:57873 
 Thread [main] (Suspended (exception ClassNotFoundException)) 
  Launcher$ExtClassLoader(URLClassLoader).findClass(String) line: 207 
  Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(String) line: 229 
  Launcher$ExtClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: 307 
  Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: 296 
  Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(String, boolean) line: 301 
  Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String) line: 248 
  InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(String, String, String) line: 280 
  InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(String, String) line: 338 
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/bin/java (Nov 30, 2010 9:40:41 PM)
```

Comment: it seems that really there is something wrong with the Java SDK/JRE installed on my iMac machine, I even got the similar error when doing 'Java -version' from inside Terminal, see the following -

Comment: tom$ Java –version
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ?version
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ?version
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)

Comment: for some reason, the above error in the Terminal is gone. But the error inside the Eclipse is still there :-(, anyone please help!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to install JDK which has complete sources? Refer to [Apple website](http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wo/5.1.17.2.1.3.3.1.0.1.1.0.3.10.3.3.1) to download the latest JDK, might need an Apple ID.

After that change eclipse's java runtime accordingly to use the new installed JDK:

[image]

And re-build your project: Project -> Source -> Clean-up